# multiprocessing.Pool.map does not work in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

What i am trying to achieve:

**Parallelize** a function that spawn a number of threads per call, like this:

```
 - PROCESS01 -> 16 Threads
 - PROCESS02 -> 16 Threads
 - ...
 - PROCESSn -> 16 Threads
```

The code:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as process_pool:
    results = process_pool.map(do_stuff, [drain_queue()])
```

Where `drain_queue()` return a list of items and

```
do_stuff(item_list):
    print('> PID: ' + str(os.getpid()))
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
        result_dict = {executor.submit(thread_function, item): item for item in item_list}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(result_dict):
            pass
```

And `thread_function()` process every item passed to it.

However, when executed the code outputs like this:

```
> PID: 1000
(WAITS UNTIL THE PROCESS FINISHES, THEN START NEXT)
> PID: 2000
(WAITS UNTIL THE PROCESS FINISHES, THEN START NEXT)
> PID: 3000
(WAITS UNTIL THE PROCESS FINISHES, THEN START NEXT)
> PID: 3000
(WAITS UNTIL THE PROCESS FINISHES, THEN START NEXT)
```

[Here is a screenshot of Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcr7d.jpg)

What am i missing here? I can't figure it out why does not work as expected.
Thanks!

Comment: Threads and processes are entirely different things. I'm not sure why you're mixing them. The Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) ensures that only one thread can execute bytecode at one time

Comment: So the serial execution is caused by the GIL which forces every process to wait for thread execution?

Comment: Actually, that's a good question. Once you launch multiprocessing, I'm not sure that threaded operations across processes should interfere with each other if they're part of separate processes. I defer an answer, I can't answer definitively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the problem. The second argument of `map()` is expected to be an iterable, where in my case was **a list containing a** **single object**.
**What is wrong ?** This: `[drain_queue()]` , which produces a list with a single object in it.

In this case, the code

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as process_pool:
    results = process_pool.map(do_stuff, [drain_queue()])
```

forces `multiprocessing.Pool.map` to "distribute" a single object to a single process, even though it creates `n` number of processes, the work will still be done by one process. Thankfully nothing to to with GIL limitations.